# Package for drawing cause effect graphs (-> software test technique)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Is there a package or a package extension for drawing cause effect graphs (see the screenshot below for atomic elements).

If there is no package can someone explain how I can achieve this by using tikz, especially the negation sign and the curved lines.

[image]

Comment: `automata` library? `pic`s? `graphs` library and declare some new standard structures?

Comment: And how is it possible for example for the automata library to define the negation symbol?

Comment: I more meant that you might find it helpful as a starting point. Obviously it is not going to provide an out-of-the-box solution. It might not be worth it, though. You might be better off just using `pic`s or `graphs`. It depends partly on the details of how you are going to need to combine these 'atomic' elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.markings,automata,angles,quotes}

\tikzset{
  myneg/.style={
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with 
        {\draw (0,0) arc (0:180:#1) (0,0) arc (180:360:#1);}
    },
    postaction=decorate
  },
  myneg/.default=6pt,
  mynode/.style={
    draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=20pt
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[mynode] (b) at (3,0) {$b$};
\draw 
  (a) -- (b) node[above=8pt,midway,font=\scshape] {identity};
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\node[mynode] (a) at (0,0) {$a$};
\node[mynode] (b) at (3,0) {$b$};
\draw[myneg] 
  (a) -- (b) node[above=8pt,midway,font=\scshape] {not};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
\node[mynode] (a) at (0,2) {$a$};
\node[mynode] (b) at (0,0) {$b$};
\node[mynode] (c) at (0,-2) {$c$};
\node[mynode] (d) at (3,0) {$d$};
\coordinate (aux) at (d.west);  
\foreach \Value in {a,b,c}
  \draw (\Value) -- (aux);
\path 
  pic[draw,angle radius=35pt,"\raisebox{20pt}{$\lor$}",
    angle eccentricity=1.25] 
  {angle=a--aux--c};  
\path (a) -- (d) node[above=12pt,midway,font=\scshape] {or};  
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm,yshift=-4cm]
\node[mynode] (a) at (0,2) {$a$};
\node[mynode] (b) at (0,-2) {$b$};
\node[mynode] (c) at (3,0) {$c$};
\foreach \Value in {a,b}
  \draw (\Value) -- (c.west);
\path 
  (a) -- (c) 
  node[above=12pt,midway,font=\scshape] {and};
\node[left=of c,font=\scshape] {$\land$};  
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The negation was obtained using a decoration (with the help of the `decorations.markings` library) and the arc for the "OR" was produced with the help of the `angles` library.

Of course, depending on the actual kind of application,  you could use additional libraries for the nodes, such as `automata` or `chains`.

An additional example showing the negation and or paths in action:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.markings,automata,angles,quotes}

\tikzset{
  myneg/.style={
    decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with 
        {\draw (0,0) arc (0:180:#1) (0,0) arc (180:360:#1);}
    },
    postaction=decorate
  },
  myneg/.default=6pt,
  mynode/.style={
    draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=20pt
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 2cm]
\node[mynode] (b) at (0,0) {$b$};
\node[mynode,above=of b] (a) {$a$};
\node[mynode,below=of b] (c) {$c$};
\node[mynode,right=of b] (d) {$d$};
\node[mynode,above right=of d] (e) {$e$};
\node[mynode,below right=of d] (f) {$f$};
\coordinate (aux) at (d.west);  
\foreach \Value in {a,b,c}
  \draw (\Value) -- (aux);
\path 
  pic[draw,angle radius=35pt,"\raisebox{20pt}{$\lor$}",
    angle eccentricity=1.25] 
  {angle=a--aux--c};  
\draw[myneg]
  (d) -- (e);
\draw[myneg]
  (d) -- (f);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]